# AlertController's code not acting right

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uialertcontroller

I have an alert pop-up with a textField requesting the user input data. I have finally gotten the textField to cast the data to where I need it, however I cannot save the item anymore. If the alertAction doesn't have an handler func attached to it, I can call the save func with no problem. Now that I have the "set" action casting the data from the textfield, it will no longer allow me to call the function. It gives an error of "expression resolves to unused function". And, for some reason it wants me to have self. before all of the data...see code.

AlertController:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (item?.slminqty == nil) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Minimun Qty", message: "Please set minimun Qty. for pantry.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField: UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Minimun Qty."
        textField.keyboardType = .NumbersAndPunctuation
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
    }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {saveitem}()))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Set", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action) -> Void in
        let textField = alert.textFields![0].text!
        self.item?.slminqty = textField
        if self.item?.slminqty != nil{
        //if I place saveitem here it wants self.saveitem and gives error.
        }
        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else{

        if item != nil {
            edititems()
            print(item!.slminqty!)
        } else {
            createitems()
        }

        dismissVC()
    }
}
```

Save function:

```
func saveitem(sender: AnyObject) {

    if item != nil {
        edititems()

    } else {
        createitems()
    }
    print(item?.slminqty)

    dismissVC()
}
```

I'm obviously doing it the extremely hard way or just wrong in general. How do I get the textField data to cast to item.slminqty and save the item?

Comment: It requires self because you're referring to an object outside the block, inside a block. If that makes sense. Retain cycles and all that. http://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the textField around, rather than the text in the textField? The UIAlertController ought to destroy when you close it, but you're currently holding on to a reference to its textField.

Comment: @ beau yes it does now. I didn't think of that. @ Michael that's the only way I could get it to work. @vishnu I've tried that and it still throws an error.

Comment: Are you sure you have `self.saveItem()` with the brackets? If you instead have just `self.saveItem`, you are referring to the saveItem function, but not calling it. That would explain the error. But you should also not pass the textField around, or it will probably cause other issues.

Comment: Yea. The self.saveitem() gives the error "missing argument for parameter #1 in call". And as far as the textField and not the text of it I couldn't get it to go another way. It would only pass nil. I've tried it a few different ways and couldn't ever get the text I had to to through the alert.textfields![0].text to get it. Which I thought was the text. It's passing what I type in there now and putting it as the item.slminqty. Just issue with saving. If there's a way to do this better and it work, I'm definitely open to it. I'm just not very knowledgable in swift yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you'll have to use self reference to call saveitems as both have different scopes. You should probably be using `self.saveitem()` inside.